# To found an inexistent word in a dictionary to give it a value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Good afternoon, this is a kind of weird question so I'll try to explain it as good as I can.

I have 2 inputs, several tweets in a list `['tweet 1', 'tweet 2',...]` and a dictionary with `{'word1': value1;'word 2': value2;...}`.

Imagine the first tweet is like:

> 'I love eating potatoes'

And from the 500 words in the dictionary there is a value for

> {...;'love': 3;...;'potatoes': -1;...}.

The words 'I', 'eating' are not included in this dictionary. So for each tweet I have, I need to search which words are NOT included in it, to give them the value score of the tweet.

Example: I love eating potatoes = 2

so

> I= 2
>
> eating=2

I have started with this:

```
tweet=[]
values={}
    for list in tweet:
        divided_tweet=list.split()
```

and to get the score I use this

```
[sum(valores.get(j, 0) for j in i.split()) for i in divided_tweet]
```

To summarize, I need to search for each tweet, each word that isn't in the dictionary to give it a value.

The print out should be:

```
'I':2

'eating':2
```

(next tweet)

```
'Inexistent word #3':'score of tweet #2' 

'Inexistent word #4':'score of tweet #2'

'Inexistent word #5':'score of tweet #2'
```

...

And so on

Can someone help me?

Thank you

P.D.: There are negative and positives values

Comment: Can you elaborate more on computing the score of the missing word?

Comment: How does 'I' and 'eating' got the values of 4?

Comment: It was a mistake, it should be ' 2 '

Comment: Is it 2 because it is the second tweet in the list of tweets? And are the missing words added to the same dictionary 500 words?

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this. I'm assuming the word values in your dictionary are ints or floats and not strings:

```
tweets=[]
values={}
for tweet in tweets:
    twit = tweet.split()        
    item_vals = []    
    not_in_tweet = []    
    for item in twit:
        #get value of words
        if item in values:
            ival = values[item]
            item_vals.append(ival)
        else: #word not in dict
            not_in_tweet.append(item)
    sum_items = sum(item_vals)
    for item in not_in_tweet:
        values[item] = sum_items
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample that gives you how to proceed:

```
>>> import re
>>> values = {'love': 3, 'potatoes': -1}
>>> tweet = 'I love eating potatoes'
>>> tweet_words = re.split("\W+", tweet)
>>> tweet_value = sum(values.get(word, 0) for word in tweet_words)
>>> {w: tweet_value for w in tweet_words if w not in values}
{'I': 2, 'eating': 2}
```

First, we split the `tweet` in words, using `re.split` on every sequence of non-word character (not a letter, a digit or an underscore). That's better than a simple `split` because you won't keep apostophes, commas, etc. Second, we compute the value of the `tweet`: `values.get(word, 0)` returns the value if the word is in `values` and `0` otherwise. Third we create a dict (you can print it as you want later) with the word not in `values` and assign them the `tweet_value`.

The two pass process is unavoidable, because you have to compute the global value begore assigning it to the unknown words.

For a full program, just do:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    d = get_unknown_word_values(tweet) # as above
    for k, v in d.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned

> So for each tweet I have, I need to search which words are NOT
>   included in it, to give them the value score of the tweet.

I assume you have a dictionary of each tweets with a value score. Example -  tweet_values_dc in the below code. If that is not the case, please let me know where and how are tweets given a value score.

```
tweets_ls = ['I love eating potatoes', 'I love eating mangoes']
tweet_values_dc = {'I love eating potatoes': 2, 'I love eating mangoes': 3}
missing_words_values_dc = {'love':3,'potatoes':-1}
for atweet in tweets_ls:
    tweet_splited = atweet.split()
    for aword in tweet_splited:
        if aword not in missing_words_values_dc.keys():
            aTweetValue = tweet_values_dc.get(atweet)
            missing_words_values_dc.update({aword:aTweetValue})
print(missing_words_values_dc)
```

Output

```
{'love': 3, 'potatoes': -1, 'I': 2, 'eating': 2, 'mangoes': 3}
```